# DLL related : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, 64-bit

I use Visual Studio 2010 Premium. I have a solution with two projects. One is the main project and the latter performs tests.
My task is to build the main project for a 64-bit platform and to check if the tests are still successful while the testing project is still built for 32-bit platform.

The test project outputs an EXE file which relies on a DLL file that the main project outputs.

If I build both the main project and the test project for 64-bit platform then everything's fine.
If I build the main project for 64-bit and then trying to build the testing project for 32-bit I get the following error types :

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

The errors refer to functions that are declared in some of the main project's header files.

Is it because I'm trying to use a 64-bit DLL file in a 32-bit build ? Is it fixable ?
I mention once again that if both projects are built for 64-bit platform then everything works fine.

Edit : to be more specific, I'll copy the prefix of 1st error line that I get :

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall ...

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the problem you're seeing is likely related to linking a 64-bit library into a 32-bit application. You'll need to build two versions of your library (32-bit and 64-bit) to go with the two versions of your application.